# Запрос с несколькими условием

Tags: mysql, sql

Пишу

```
SELECT ic.icraci_id, COUNT(m.m_id) as m
FROM dataicraci d1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(i_id) AS i_id, data_id FROM dataicraci GROUP BY data_id) AS tmp ON d1.`i_id` = tmp.i_id AND d1.`data_id` = tmp.`data_id`
JOIN (SELECT icraci_id, iwci, position FROM icracilar) AS ic on ic.icraci_id = tmp.i_id
JOIN (SELECT m_id, data_id FROM meruze) AS m on m.data_id = d1.data_id
JOIN (SELECT id, input_date, meruze_date FROM data) AS d on d.id = d1.data_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(d.input_date, '%Y') = 2017 AND m.m_id = 5
GROUP BY tmp.i_id ORDER BY ic.position
```

все нормально работает, а когда к условию добавляю еще  `AND m.m_id = 6` MySQL возвращает пустой результат

Comment: Выберите данные без этого условия, и убедитесь, что у вас просто нет подходящих данных с m_id=6

Comment: Или вы при этом забываете убрать условие m_id=5 а никой m_id не может быть одновременно равен и 5 и 6

Comment: мне надо чтобы он выбирал и 5 и 6 одновременно

Comment: AND (m.m_id = 5 OR m.m_id = 6 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Чтобы добавить еще одно условие, используйте `OR` или `IN`.
2. Для вытаскивания года в MySQL есть `year(your date)`.

В результате запрос будет:

```
SELECT ic.icraci_id, COUNT(m.m_id) as m
FROM dataicraci d1
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(i_id) AS i_id, data_id
          FROM dataicraci
          GROUP BY data_id
         ) AS tmp
       ON d1.`i_id` = tmp.i_id AND d1.`data_id` = tmp.`data_id`
    JOIN icracilar AS ic on ic.icraci_id = tmp.i_id
    JOIN meruze AS m on m.data_id = d1.data_id
    JOIN data AS d on d.id = d1.data_id
WHERE YEAR(d.input_date) = 2017 AND m.m_id in (5,6)
GROUP BY tmp.i_id
ORDER BY ic.position
```

Comment: @Mike кстати, да, не обратил внимание :)

Comment: @Mike Благодарю! я думаю что скобки оставлю т.к. я выбираю не все поля из этих таблиц

Comment: @Denis И вам спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev пожалуйста. Имхо, так код читабельней, когда вы присваиваете таблицу без обязательного выбора нескольких полей + никогда не знаете, может еще поле понадобится. Но, это мое мнение :)

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev Вы же все равно в итоге пишите не `*`, в берете только нужное на выводе, так что оптимизатор сам разберется какие поля нужны, а какие нет. ничего лишнего он вытаскивать не будет. Да и что там вытаскивать, если запись все равно поднимается с диска целиком. А вот вероятность того, что оптимизатор не догадается сам раскрыть скобки и пойдет по таблице полным перебором, вместо использования индексов, высока. И если это произойдет получите катастрофическое падение производительности.

Comment: Благодарю за объяснение! Теперь буду делать только так